# multi sheet export using angular ngx-export-as

Tags: excel, angular, typescript

I am using [ngx-export-as](https://github.com/wnabil/ngx-export-as) in angular I want export a excel file to have two and more sheet in excel
How can I make this export?

I make this issue in [github](https://github.com/wnabil/ngx-export-as/issues/82) about this

Comment: what are you using for backend code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use the kendo excel export for angular, also have many samples for your problem.
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/

Comment: I Want excel . I dont find excel export

Comment: In left side menu you see excel export. or use this link ,I hope useful. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/

Comment: need to purchase a license??